# Parsing winlayout() For Toggling Multiple Windows At Once

Tags: vim-windows, terminal-buffer, window-management, original-vim

When working in `vim`, I like to have a toggle-able terminal window that I can bring with me from tab to tab. This works by tracking a buffer, and opening it in a new `bot` split (if it isn't visible), or hiding the split (if it is visible). However, my current solution only allows me to use a single terminal buffer at a time.

I am trying to write a set of functions that allows me to manage and toggle a "set" of terminal buffers, all of which are next to each other and at the bottom of the screen. My method so far is to store a list of each terminal window as it is opened, with something like:

```
[{'bufnr': 2, 'type': 'root'}, {'bufnr': 3, 'type': 'v'}, {'bufnr': 4, 'type': 'h'}]
```

I can then iterate through these and open them in the same order that they were originally opened. This is fine, except for when any of the buffers in the set is closed. There are a ton of different edge cases, so I've been looking for a better solution.

`vim` provides the function `winlayout()` that I could potentially filter down to only windows that are in the terminal set, but I am having an incredibly hard time parsing out the information that it returns.

Could someone help me figure out how to parse the output of `winlayout()` to reproduce the layout it defines? Or, if there is a better way to do this, I am always open to ideas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Full restore

If you want to restore layout with multiple termina buffers, you must restore other windows and buffers too, so it's in fact a full buffer layout restore, it's usage is not limited to terminal buffers. Three things must be done to achive that:

- Split windows according to saved layout. We can use result of `winlayout()` to do this.
- Load buffer in each window. We must record `bufnr` in each window when we save `winlayout()`.
- Resize each window. We can use `:h winrestcmd()` to do this.

Two recursions are used to save and restore layout:

```
command SaveBufferLayout call s:save_buffer_layout()
command RestoreBufferLayout call s:restore_buffer_layout()

function s:save_buffer_layout() abort
  let s:buf_layout = winlayout()
  let s:resize_cmd = winrestcmd()
  call s:add_buf_to_layout(s:buf_layout)
endfunction

" add bufnr to leaf
function s:add_buf_to_layout(layout) abort
  if a:layout[0] ==# 'leaf'
    call add(a:layout, winbufnr(a:layout[1]))
  else
    for child_layout in a:layout[1]
      call s:add_buf_to_layout(child_layout)
    endfor
  endif
endfunction

function s:restore_buffer_layout() abort
  if !has_key(s:, 'buf_layout')
    return
  endif

  " create clean window
  new
  wincmd o

  " recursively restore buffers
  call s:apply_layout(s:buf_layout)

  " resize
  exe s:resize_cmd
endfunction

function s:apply_layout(layout) abort

  if a:layout[0] ==# 'leaf'
    if bufexists(a:layout[2])
      exe printf('b %d', a:layout[2])
    endif
  else

    " split cols or rows, split n-1 times
    let split_method = a:layout[0] ==# 'col' ? 'rightbelow split' : 'rightbelow vsplit'
    let wins = [win_getid()]
    for child_layout in a:layout[1][1:]
      exe split_method
      let wins += [win_getid()]
    endfor

    " recursive into child windows
    for index in range(len(wins) )
      call win_gotoid(wins[index])
      call s:apply_layout(a:layout[1][index])
    endfor

  endif
endfunction
```

It's possible to make it work for multiple layouts, you can the newest script [here](https://github.com/dedowsdi/.vim/blob/master/autoload/misc/layout.vim).

### Original manual workaround

It's trouble and buggy to toggle multiple terminal windows, you can step back, split by manual, then load the hided terminal buffer by `mark` or buffer number.

You can create global mark for terminal buffer by `<c-w>:mark X` or `<c-w>:kX`, hide it, and load it back with `'X`, here is a map that let you create mark with `<c-w>m{capital letter}`:

```
tnoremap <expr> <c-w>m printf('<c-w>:mark %s<cr>',  nr2char(getchar()))
```

Note that you can also combine the `split` and `load` together in a single command:

```
new +'X
```

You can also use `:ls R` or `:ls F` to list terminal buffer.

---

### winlayout

`:h winlayout()`

```
        The result is a nested List containing the layout of windows
        in a tabpage.
                ...
        For a leaf window, it returns:
            ['leaf', {winid}]
        For horizontally split windows, which form a column, it
        returns:
            ['col', [{nested list of windows}]]
        For vertically split windows, which form a row, it returns:
            ['row', [{nested list of windows}]]
```

`leaf` item contains `:h winid` , it's an uique id across `tabs`.

This is a horizontally splited `col`, it has 3 leafs:

```
┌─────┐
│     │
├─────┤
│     │
├─────┤
│     │
└─────┘
```

This is a vertically splited `row`, it has 3 leafs:

```
┌────┬────┬────┐
│    │    │    │
└────┴────┴────┘
```

They can be `nested`, this layout is a `row`, it's splited into two `col`, each
`col` is splited into two leafs:

```
 ┌──────┬──────┐
 │  1   │  3   │
 ├──────│──────┤
 │  2   │  4   │
 └──────┴──────┘
```

this layout is a `col`, it's splited into two `row`, each
`row` is splited into two leafs:

```
 ┌──────┬──────┐
 │  1   │  2   │
 ├─────────────┤
 │  3   │  4   │
 └──────┴──────┘
```

Note that `:h winnr()` for above two layouts are different.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the methods you'd discussed for using `mark` which is pretty convenient and works similar to the methods that I use now. The real problem here is the logic surrounding some complex nesting of `terminal` buffer windows, hence why I'd looked into `winlayout()`. From what I understand there is no related function to recreate the return of a call to `winlayout()`, right? In this case, would my best bet to parsing this list structure be using recursion?

Comment: @ThoseKind See update, I've tested it with about 10 windows.

Comment: This is amazing man, thank you so much.

Comment: Amazing! I want the plugin to silently save stack of layouts on window splits and a mapping to restore the latest. Like emacs folks have. Will play with it, thx!