# Split window size change event

Tags: vimscript, autocmd, split

Couldn't find anything in `autocommand-events`, but is there may be a way to be notified if window split size was changed (with mouse or with `C-w +`)?

What I try to achieve is to be able to auto-save the window layout if size was changed.

PS: that is for my WIP plugin https://github.com/habamax/vim-winlayout which is heavily inspired by and uses code from [@dedowsdi answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22543/parsing-winlayout-for-toggling-multiple-windows-at-once/22545#22545)

Comment: Or maybe I should add timer event for this? Checking current win sizes against previous?

Comment: Yeah i saw that this morning. Didn't find any winresized events unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

One undocumented trick is to use `%{MyFunc()}` expression in the statusline syntax. `MyFunc()` is always called whenever something happens so you can check the window size in it.

For example, You can see the window height/width in the statusline.

```
function! EchoWinSize()
   return winheight(0) . '/' . winwidth(0)
endfunction
let &statusline = "%{EchoWinSize()}"
```

As well as the statusline, guitablabel, iconstring, rulerformat, tabline, titlestring options support the statusline syntax.

However, I am not sure about its negative side effect.

I found this trick since
I have been looking for something like a WindowScrolled event,
but not yet implemented.
In my plugin, I am thinking to use iconstring, which seems not to be used so common, to check the window scroll.