# Does Vim have functionality similar to tmux's `display-panes` command for selecting (goto) a specific window by number?

Tags: terminal, vim-windows, tmux, mouse, jump

> Does Vim have functionality similar to tmux's `display-panes` command
>   for selecting (goto) a specific window by number?

Sometimes when I've many windows open, it can be a pain to navigate them by `C-w h` (left), `C-w j` (down), `C-w k` (up), and `C-w l` (right). In that case, I miss functionality similar to `tmux`'s `display-panes` command, which lets me select (goto) a specific pane by its number:

```
bind-key    -T prefix       q                     display-panes
```

Does `vim` have similar functionality?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not aware of any Vim feature or even plugin that does that; in fact, up until recently it would be rather hard to display it like that, but with Vim 8.2's [popup windows](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/24462/51) it wouldn't be too hard; you just have to loop over all visible windows and create a new popup window displaying the window number.

The closest thing you can get, which may actually be enough, is displaying the window number in the statusline by adding `%{winnr()}`; you can then use `[nr]<C-w>w` to switch to a specific window.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of any approximate functionality, like labeling windows and then moving to a window by its label, or is there a command for moving to the last-visited window (i.e., jump between two windows)?

Comment: @Shuzheng You can use `CTRL-W p` to jump to the last visited window, which will effectively jump between two windows when used repeatedly.

Comment: @filbranden - Thank you. But there is no way to jump to a specific window except using `Ctrl-w h`, `Ctrl-w j`, ...?

Comment: @Shuzheng If you know the window number (for instance by including it in the status line, like Martin suggests), then you can use `<count> CTRL-W w` to jump to that window directly. Even if you don't have the number in the status line, windows are numbered from top-left to bottom-right, so you should be able to count to the one you would like to jump too...

Comment: @filbranden Window number is determined by layout, it's totally possible to number window by `top-left`, `top-right`, `bottom-left`, `bottom-right`. See end of https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22545/5017 for an example.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [Choosewin](https://github.com/t9md/vim-choosewin), sadly [it's not being actively developed anymore](https://github.com/t9md/vim-choosewin/issues/45#issuecomment-450544629), but for the simplest use cases it works great.

Comment: Looks like that plugin works by creating a new buffer with the same text, and then adding and highlighting some characters to draw a number. It then switches the actual buffer out for the new one, and back when you select it. Clever, but rather ugly, and apparently with some side-effects. With popup windows in Vim 8.2 it's no longer needed, so that plugin can be simplified a lot now.

Comment: Agree, it actually has several corner cases so I used the mode that only changes the status line

Answer (score 2):

## With vim only

There's a few options to make navigation between files less tedious in vanilla vim.

First, you probably want to have `set switchbuf=useopen` in your vimrc (`:h 'switchbuf'`) to reuse a split, instead of opening the buffer in the current split.

If you have the buffer number in `'statusline'` (i.e `%n`), you can then easily switch to a split by number with `:sbuffer buffnumber`.

This will also work if you give a unique pattern from the name. If you are in the split 'foo' and have two more splits 'bar' and 'baz', `:sbuffer az` will switch to the 'baz' split.

You can have a mapping to make it easier: `nnoremap <leader>b :sbuffer`  (there's a space at the end).

Also, those mappings help switch to different splits (`:h windows`):

- `<c-w>t` -> top left split
- `<c-w>b` -> bottom right split
- `<c-w>p` -> last used split

## With FZF

Besides, could use [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) plugin (requires [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki)) and its `:Buffers` command.

Similarly to `switchbuf=useopen`, you'll want `let g:fzf_buffers_jump = 1` in your vimrc to reuse an open split.

The command will show a list of buffers which you can strip down with fuzzy search, and navigate with `<c-j>` and `<c-k>`

`<Enter>` will then switch to the split if already open, or else use the current one. `<c-v>`, `<c-x>` or `<c-t>` will open the buffer in a new vertical split, horizontal split or tab.

You could have a mapping to launch `:Buffers` like `nnoremap <leader>b :Buffers<cr>`.

Comment: `:Windows` is another fzf command that shows the window numbers along with tabs.

Comment: FZF for the win here! The `:Windows` and `:Buffers` commands wth the plugin were really cool. I do wish Vim/Neovim had a way to list split numbers and jump between them easier than having to modify the statusline.

Answer (score 1):

I found a plugin that does exactly this.

I have been using for a whole hour now, so I feel comfortable recommending it to the world.

[image: Look at it go!]

https://github.com/t9md/vim-choosewin

In particular, I've been using this configuration:

```
" Invoke choosewin plugin using tab
nmap  <Tab>  <Plug>(choosewin)
"Use overlay feature for choosewin
let g:choosewin_overlay_enable = 1
```

But I have not play around with other options, it seems to be pretty configurable, go nuts!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0):

It might not be a direct answer, but if you just need to jump between buffers you can use `:bN`, where `N` is the number of the buffer, which you can check with the `:ls` command.

I rarely need to use more than 3 panes in one direction and I just use the `:bN` command. If you work long enough with the files, you will remember their buffer number.

Answer (score 0):

If you never have more than 9 windows then with a tiny bit of config you can jump to any window with `<leader>` + window number.  Or you can jump to the previous window with `<leader>0`.

This relies on your status line showing the window number so you know what each window's number is.

Here's the config:

```
" Jump to window <n>:
" http://stackoverflow.com/a/6404246/151007
for i in range(1, 9)
  execute 'nnoremap <Leader>'.i.' :'.i.'wincmd w<CR>'
endfor
" Jump to previous window:
execute 'nnoremap <Leader>0 :wincmd p<CR>'
```

Additionally I map tab and shift-tab to cycle through the windows.  Sometimes it's quicker to hammer tab a few times than look at the window's status line and type `<leader>7` or whatever it may be.

```
nnoremap <Tab> <C-W>w
nnoremap <S-Tab> <C-W>W
```